# When using SQLite3 and ExpressJs how do I make sure app.get() is not asynchronous while calling a db.each() method?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, asynchronous

I have some front end code that would make a GET request to the url "/api/classes". When triggered my ExpressJs back-end will load my SQLite3 database, then read the query, and finally store the result inside an object and return it. I am using the db.each() method to loop my database. I know my loop works because of the console.log template strings. The problem is when I use PostMan I can see that res.send() gets called immediately, which returns an empty object. How do I make sure res.send() gets called after db.each()? I know db.each() accepts a callback so I tried to place res.send() as an argument, but that did not work.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
let sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const app = express();

app.get('/api/classes', (req, res) => {
    let classes = {}
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./classes.db', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Connected to the classes database.');
    });   
    let sql = `SELECT CRS_CDE course_code,
                  CRS_TITLE course_name,
                  Column3 start_time,
                  Column4 end_time
            FROM spring_schedule
            WHERE CRS_TITLE IN `;

    let classNames = ['Spanish I', 'Accounting II', 'College Algebra']
    let where = '(?' + ',?'.repeat(classNames.length-1) + ')';
    sql += where;

    db.each(sql, [...classNames], (err, row) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`${row.course_code} + ${row.course_name} +  ${row.start_time} - ${row.end_time}`);
        classes[row.course_code] = row.course_name
    });
    db.close();
    res.send(classes)
});

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` function has a [complete] callback according to the api docs [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete)
so your example should be like that:

```
   db.each(sql, [...classNames], (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
    throw err;
    }
    console.log(`${row.course_code} + ${row.course_name} +  ${row.start_time} -              
     ${row.end_time}`);

    classes[row.course_code] = row.course_name

  }, () => {

          res.send(classes)

      });
```